# How can I search answers that consist mostly block quotes?

Tags: discussion

The more a block quote consists an answer, the higher up the result must be. Of course I'm not asking for answers that are 100% blockquotes. I'm also interested in answers that are 70-99% blockquotes. I don't know how to program and appreciate your assistance!  I'd appreciate

1. one search engine for all Stack Exchanges.
2. another for a specific Stack Exchange that I picked. Thanks!

[Here's a (downvoted) example from ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/48353), [an upvoted example from ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/257160).

### Reason

For those  Hot Network Questions are already fully answered on other sites, I'm curious if people just quote from those other sites, or in fact answer the same question in their own words! But this isn't the point of this post.

Comment: This query to find posts that are mostly spoilers can be easily modified to do what you want: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299391/323179

Comment: @laurel the OP said they don't know how to program?

Comment: there's no search engine, but you can ask for an SQL query at data.stackexchange.com , also I dont think it can scan network wide (time issues and probably no such functionality), but it should work for a specific site.